# How to change string into integer and add them?

Tags: java, string, integer

Im writing a code that will will take the entered number and only add the values that are in the even positions.

For example:

If user enters 53429
The sum of of the even positions is 5.

My issue is I'm trying to convert the strings of the even positions back into integers and add them together. This is what I have

I keep receiving an error when I try to parse the string to an integer.

```
    Cannot find symbol
    symbol  : method parseInt(java.lang.String)
    location: class Integer
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NumberSums { 
    public static void main(String [] args) { 

        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter a number: "); 
        String x=keyboard.next(); 

        String s1 = x; 
        int length = s1.length(); 

        if (length<5) { 
            System.out.println("Invalid value"); 
            System.exit(0); 
        } 

        if (length>5) { 
            System.out.println("Invalid value"); 
            System.exit(0); 
        } 

        String s2 = s1.substring(0,1); 
        String s3 = s1.substring(1,2);
        String s4 = s1.substring(2,3); 
        String s5 = s1.substring(3,4);
        String s6 = s1.substring(4,5);

        int a = Integer.parseInt(s3);
        //int b = Integer.parseInt(s5);

        //sum = (a + b);

        System.out.println("The sum of all even positions is " + sum); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Care explaining where you are getting error if any?

Comment: Im getting an error when I try to parse the string to an integer

Comment: what kind of error/exception? Possibly post an error log.

Comment: If you use 53429 then String s6 = s1.substring(4,5); will generate ArrayIndexOutOfBoundExceptions.

Comment: Just for fun, I made a one-line Python solution at  http://ideone.com/NP8Wxp

Answer (score 6):

I'm willing to bet that you have a class named `Integer`, and Java is trying to use that rather than `java.lang.Integer`.

Rename your class, or use `java.lang.Integer.parseInt(s3)` instead.

Comment: I am inclining to this answer, I tried copy pasting OP's code and I got no errors whatsoever..

Comment: @KubaSpatny Except that the `sum` variable isn't defined in the pasted code :)

Answer (score 2):

code to add even placed chars in the string.

```
 String str="1234567";
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=1;i<str.length();i=i+2){
            sum+=(str.charAt(i)-'0');
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

And we can also take from keyboard and start the calculation:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Please enter number : ");
    String number=null;
    try{
        number = reader.readLine();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=1;i<number.length();i=i+2){
        sum+=(number.charAt(i)-'0');
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran the program and it works fine... if you uncomment the lines `int b` and `sum = (a + b);`. However, you have to declare the `sum` variable, i.e. `int sum = (a + b);`

What JDK are you running? The error you describe would only occur if `Integer.parseInt(String foo);` didn't exist, except it's been around since at least Java 1.4, so I'm not sure why you wouldn't find it; unless you have another `Integer` class defined in the same package, which could confuse the compiler.

Here is the complete program, including imports (which may be the problem, if you're importing a different `Integer` than `java.lang.Integer`), fixing the variable declaration and removing unnecessary code, fixing indentation, and adding a `Scanner.close()` statement:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    { 
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter a number: "); 
        String x=keyboard.next(); 

        String s1 = x; 
        int length = s1.length(); 

        if(length != 5) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Invalid value"); 
            System.exit(0); 
        } 

        String s3 = s1.substring(1,2);
        String s5 = s1.substring(3,4);

        int a = Integer.parseInt(s3);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(s5);

        int sum = (a + b);

        System.out.println("The sum of all even positions is " + sum); 

        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Modified code. Try understanding it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EvenPos {

public static void main(String [] args) 
{ 

Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Enter a number: "); 
String x=keyboard.next(); 

String s1 = x; 
int length = s1.length(); 

if(length<5) { 
    System.out.println("Invalid value"); 
    System.exit(0); 
    } 

if(length>5) { 
    System.out.println("Invalid value"); 
    System.exit(0); 
    } 

else{

char a = s1.charAt(1);
char b = s1.charAt(3);
int q = Character.getNumericValue(a); //Convert Char to Integer
int z = Character.getNumericValue(b); // //Convert Char to Integer

int sum = 0;
if (q % 2 == 0 && z % 2 == 0){ //If both even, then.....
    sum = q+z;
    System.out.println("Your sum: " + sum);
}
else{
    System.out.println("No even Number found at even POS");
}
```

}

}
}